# What is the best strategy to delete Apex and VF classes from a live org?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

If I want to delete a bunch of classes and visualforce from the prod org, how do I go about doing this? Especially if there are dependencies like one class references another class.

Comment: Anup - it appears you are answering your own questions intentionally. Did you ask this on July 13th, 15:36, discover the answer, and then post your results on July 13th at 15:36?

Comment: yes, that's correct! I was using the answer your own question feature so that it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a Force.com project in the Eclipse force.com ide, and delete the class(es) and Visualforce page(s) directly from the IDE.

It might not delete your class or page if your test coverage is less than 75%.

Anup